# ErrorVariable not working with null or empty agrument

Tags: powershell, error-handling

I am having issues with `-ErrorVariable` capturing an error if the argument is null or empty. Here is an example:

```
PS> Get-Process $svc

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K) VM(M)   CPU(s)     Id ProcessName          
-------  ------    -----      ----- -----   ------     -- -----------          
    374      14     5180       4996    49             596 svchost  

PS> get-process $noProcess -ErrorVariable MyErr 
Get-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is 
null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the 
command again.
At line:1 char:13
+ get-process $noProcess -ErrorVariable MyErr
+             ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBinding 
   ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Power 
   Shell.Commands.GetProcessCommand


PS> $MyErr  # <----ErrorVariable did not capture error 
PS> $Error[0]
Get-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
```

Any thoughts as to why `-ErrorVariable` would not work in this case? I have tested it on other cmdlets and PowerShell 3.0/4.0 and still see the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error didn't show up in the error variable because the error wasn't thrown by Get-Process. It was thrown by the command processor trying to validate the parameters so it could run Get-Process.  Get-Process never got to run, so it never had a chance to put anything into the variable.

Possible workaround:

```
try{ 
    Get-Process $noprocess -ErrorVariable MyErr
   }
 Catch { $MyErr = $Error[0] }

 $MyErr
Get-Process : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or 
empty, and then try the command again.
At line:3 char:17
+     Get-Process $noprocess -ErrorVariable MyErr
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Process], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. It was driving me crazy.